# Unexpected css position:absolute behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I have a problem with my `css` position. For example when I set `position absolute` on elements they get space on page but won't show.My code goes as follows *(I did it on the some old tabb box i use to have)*. Hope somebody knows solution to this one,any help would be much appreciated!

```js
$(".tabBoxContainer").css({
  "position": "absolute",
  "top": "50px",
  "float": "none",
  "z-index": "100"
});
```

```css
#tabBoxContent {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tabBoxContainer {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: #232323;
}

.fixedTabContent {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 50px !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}

.tabBoxArticle {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tabBoxArticle img {
  width: 90%;
}

.tabBoxArticle h1 a {
  color: #222 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="tabBoxContent">
  <div class="tabBoxContainer" id="tabBoxHTML">
    <div class="tabBoxArticle">
      <img src="img/juneca-rebra.jpg" alt="">
      <h1><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tabBoxArticle">
      <img src="img/jaja-sa-sunkom.jpg" alt="">
      <h1><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tabBoxArticle">
      <img src="img/keciga.jpg" alt="">
      <h1><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#tabBoxContainer -->
  <div class="tabBoxContainer" id="tabBoxCSS">
    <div class="tabBoxArticle">
      <img src="img/piletina-na-mlimarski-nacin.jpg" alt="">
      <h1><a href="#">Somme dummy long article title</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tabBoxArticle">
      <img src="img/pohovana-paprika.jpg" alt="">
      <h1>Somme dummy long article title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tabBoxArticle">
      <img src="img/pohovani-sir.jpg" alt="">
      <h1>Somme dummy long article title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#tabBoxContainer -->
  <div class="tabBoxContainer" id="tabBoxJQuery">
    <div class="tabBoxArticle">
      <img src="img/rriblji-paprikas.jpg" alt="">
      <h1>Dummy long article title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tabBoxArticle">
      <img src="img/sat1.jpg" alt="">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tabBoxArticle">
      <img src="img/satova-zakuska.jpg" alt="">
      <h1>Dummy long article title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#tabBoxContainer -->
</section>
<!-- /#tabBoxContent -->
```

I have also tried with adding a class with `jquery` but it won't display it when I set absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your `#tabBoxContent` CSS that's breaking it. If you remove the `overflow: auto`, it should make the absolutely positioned elements show again.

Then again, it's not obvious what you're exactly trying to achieve, based on your question, or why you put the `overflow: auto` on it in the first place.